# RamdaJS lib curry syntax breakdown

Tags: javascript, closures, currying, ramda.js

I'm not sure what this or arguments applies to in curry function, since arguments binds to hosting function, in which case that is "a" which I don't belief actually gets used anywhere.

```
var _isPlaceholder = require('./_isPlaceholder');
/**
 * Optimized internal one-arity curry function.
 *
 * @private
 * @category Function
 * @param {Function} fn The function to curry.
 * @return {Function} The curried function.
 */
module.exports = function _curry1(fn) {
  return function f1(a) {
    if (arguments.length === 0 || _isPlaceholder(a)) {
      return f1;
    } else {
      return fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  };
};

var _curry1 = require('./internal/_curry1'); 
/**
 * Creates a new object from a list key-value pairs. If a key appears in
 * multiple pairs, the rightmost pair is included in the object.
 *
 * @func
 * @memberOf R
 * @since v0.3.0
 * @category List
 * @sig [[k,v]] -> {k: v}
 * @param {Array} pairs An array of two-element arrays that will be the keys and values of the output object.
 * @return {Object} The object made by pairing up `keys` and `values`.
 * @see R.toPairs, R.pair
 * @example
 *
 *      R.fromPairs([['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]); //=> {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
 */
module.exports = _curry1(function fromPairs(pairs) {
  var result = {};
  var idx = 0;
  while (idx < pairs.length) {
    result[pairs[idx][0]] = pairs[idx][1];
    idx += 1;
  }
  return result;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of `arguments` here simply allows more than one argument to be applied to the function, while ensuring at least one non-[placeholder](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#__) argument is provided.

The binding of `this` just ensures that the underlying function is called with the same `this` that the curried functions is evaluated with.

Comment: So what is a of f1, argumens of fn, because wouldn't calling arguments in f1 refer to a?

Comment: `a` and `arguments[0]` are both references to the same argument. If `isPlaceholder(a)` were replaced with `isPlaceholder(arguments[0])` then you could remove `a`, however it is useful to keep `a` as an argument so that `f1.length == 1`.

Comment: So isn't curry1(fn)(a) is when a gets used, how is it that that you can refer to pairs as a?

Comment: `_curry1` is a near-useless function, but it adds some consistency to Ramda functions.  If you call `curry(fn3args)(__, __, c)` you get back essentially `(a, b) => fn3args(a, b, c)`.   And `curry(fn3args)(__, b, c)` yields `a => fn3args(a, b, c)`.  And `curry(fn3args)(a, __, c)` yields `b => fn3args(a, b, c)`.  So too with `curry(fn2args)(__, b)` becomes `a => fn2args(a, b)`.  To make this consistent, the internal `_curry1` ensures that `curry(fn1arg)(__)` gives back the original function, equivalent to `a => fn1arg(a)`.  That's all it's for.

Comment: So in this case fn3args would be _curry3? Does this explain how "a" of f1 binds to fn params?